# send automated messages to various whatsApp users using this xpath to click send started not to work

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I used send automated messages to various whatsApp users using this xpath code to click on the send button.
`navegador.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]').send_keys(Keys.SEND)`

It recently stopped working saying that it can't find the xpath.
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/button"} (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.124)`

I've tried updating the xpath as it seams to have changed to:
`//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/button`
But I still get the same error message.

I've also seen one thread suggesting that the driver may not be set for the current page. If so, how do I fix that?
[selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61757397/selenium-common-exceptions-elementnotinteractableexception-message-element-not)

What am 'I missing?

Thanks in advance for any help on this mater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly your locator is not correct.
Also, the send element button appears with a short delay after the text is inserted into the message text area.
Try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[@data-testid="send"]'))).click()
```

Comment: Thank you so, so much for that. it saved me. I spent hours on this.